# Can someone explain to me what the square brackets do here in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, split

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#switcher-default').addClass('selected');
$('#switcher button').on('click', function(){

    var bodyClass = this.id.split('-')[1];

    $('body').removeClass().addClass(bodyClass);
    $('#switcher button').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    console.log(bodyClass);
});
});

//////////////Html Code/////////////

<div id="switcher" class="switcher">
    <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
    <button id="switcher-default">
        Default
    </button>
    <button id="switcher-narrow">
        Narrow Column
    </button>
    <button id="switcher-large">
        Large Print
    </button>
</div>
```

This code works and I can see what it does as well but the 1 in the square brackets is confusing me. Does it mean to split the id where "-" is used and take the first part? I don't really know? Would apreaciate the help.

Comment: `split()` returns an array of *n* elements, `[i]` accesses the `i`th element of that array.

Comment: Just as a side note, ID should never bring any data. You have `data-*` attribute for that. All that to say this code is bad

Comment: @A.Wolff: I wouldn't say "never." If you need an `id` for your element for other reasons, and you also need to know the unique identifier of something that element represents (like a blog comment), I see no issue whatsoever with making that ID part of the `id` (as they do in the comments in [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp/#div-comment-77733)).

Answer (score 0):

It means that you split the string identified by **this.id**, which results in an array. You use the value with index 1 from this array to set variable **bodyClass**.

Note that in many settings when you are not the one generating all the data, it may be unsafe to assume that the resulting array always has a particular number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `this.id.split('-')` is an array. Thus `[1]` retrieves the item at index 1.

would be equivalent to:

```
//get array of ids
var ids = this.id.split('-');
//get 1st id
var bodyClass = ids[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.id` could be 'switcher-whatever'
`this.id.split('-')` is equals to ['switcher','whatever'] 
`this.id.split('-')[1]` is taking the second element  'whatever'

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand it.